# Core data attribute not being made

Tags: iphone, core-data, attributes

I've decided to add an NSNumber attribute to one of my entities in core data. I Cleaned the code and deleted the app from the simulator. I then added the following code in my appDelegate and it tells me that my NSNumber attribute doesn't exist.

```
People *PeopleA = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"People" inManagedObjectContext:context];
PeopleA.name = @"Paul";
PeopleA.number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:12];
```

The name attribute works just fine, that was made before and it's always worked. But when it gets to `PeopleA.number` it crashes with :

```
-[People setNumber:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d5eeb0
```

So I did a `po 0x4d5eeb0` and saw that there is a name attribute but not one for number. My core data class should be good because I had XCode make it for me.

What could possibly be the issue?

Here is my People.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@class Group;

@interface People : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) id image;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * number;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Group * group;

@end
```

People.m

```
#import "People.h"
#import "Group.h"

@implementation People
@dynamic name;
@dynamic image;
@dynamic number;
@dynamic group;

@end
```

po 0x4d5eeb0 gets me:

```
<People: 0x5932290> (entity: People; id: 0x59322f0 <x-coredata:///People/t83A9C7D9-4F7A-4189-9EC5-7695968A29552> ; data: {
    group = nil;
    name = Paul;
```

Comment: Please post your `People.h` contents.

Comment: I edited the post to include 'People.h'

Comment: did you synthesized your `number` property in `People.m` file? Do you have `@dynamic number;`?

Comment: Yes, that's the only reason it got created in People.h and People.m. XCode made those files because number is an attribute.

Comment: OK, I thought you might have edited those files by hand rather than having Xcode re-create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When in doubt, delete it out.

I ended up deleting my two xcdatamodel files and the xcdatamodeld file. Also deleted them in their respective folders. Then I created a new one. Had some issues at first but it actually works now.

I have a little issue with xcode thinking that my `Group.h` file doesn't have an `addPeople` method, which it does. So it says that it may not respond to that method, or any of its other methods. It also throws me a `Lexical or Preprocessor Issue: 'Group.h' file not found` error at build-time, but everything seems to still work.

I still have no idea what was going on. Thanks to everyone for their suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Printing the object in the debugger should give you all the properties defined in the class regardless of whether it is a NSManagedObject subclass held by a context or just a plain vanilla custom class. The debugger printout is not only missing the `number` property but the `image` one as well.

Really, the only way that could happen was if you didn't have the new version of the class file added to the target but were actually using the old version that lacked the new properties.

Check the target for the old files and/or check that the new version has been properly added to the build target.

Comment: +1 excellent point re: checking the targets for the file. One of the most powerful and least user friendly features of XCode.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you're talking about but I went to my Target called Pick --> Build Phases tab --> Compile Sources dropdown, and I saw that Pick.xcdatamodeld was there and Pick.xcdatamodel was there but not my new version Pick 2.xcdatamodel. Could this be the problem. If so, how do I fix this?

Comment: Just remove the old version with the "-" button and add the new with the "+". This is where you can customize the files that are compiled to source. Usually this is setup and maintained automatically by Xcode but when you swap a lot of things around it can get confused. BTW, does `Pick 2.xcdatamodel` have a space in it? If so, you might want to change that to an underscore just in case.

Comment: Whoops, just realized that the class files for People.h an People.m must also be off version. The debugger would show the class properties even if class and entity no longer lined up perfectly because (1) you can have non-modeled properties in managed object subclasses and (2) the debugger doesn't know anything Core Data, it just prints the object at the address.

Answer (score 1):

Try naming the `number` attribute something different, such as `theNumber`. There are several known [reserved words in Core Data attributes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSPropertyDescription_Class/NSPropertyDescription.html), and an unknown number (no pun intended) which are not documented - you may have stumbled onto another one.

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of the data model (through the 'add version' menu)? If so you might have the wrong one selected as the 'current version'

Comment: At first I thought you were right, but the version I changed has a checkmark next to it so it's the current one. Plus, the old version doesn't have an 'order' attribute for my group and the checkmarked one does and I'm able to set the order for it and print it. Darn, I was hoping that was it.

Comment: This is quite a boggler. Can you post the project somewhere I can take a look at it? You might try deleting the derived data directory for the project - it can be done from within the Organizer of XCode. It won't delete any source code, just indexes, cached object files, that kind of stuff. Basically, it forces a *real* clean build. I've found that sometimes core data build output gets into a funky state, and that is required to shake it loose.

Comment: +1 Good practice even if it doesn't resolve the immediate problem. Objective-C's open name space can bite you on the hindquarters if you are not careful.